# Any event for reset button on click of input type=search?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Is there any event available for clicking reset button appears on html5 search input element?

Comment: i didn't know html5 had a input type search

Comment: no compatibility with mozila,ie and opera, pretty bad, better stick with the plain old text type

Comment: nope dude..i cant change code bcz i am working on dynamic input which was used in datatables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The event is called `search`. It is fired on both: the search and the reset.
You just need to check if the query is empty or not.

For example:

```
$("#searchInput").on("search", function(evt){
    if($(this).val().length > 0){
        // the search is being executed
    }else{
        // user clicked reset
    }
});
```

It works, here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ye1dabap/

Comment: is reset/search implemented in jquery?

Comment: No, it's not, you need to use $.on("search", function(){});

Comment: then what is the perfect answer?

Comment: @NageshwarReddy let OP finish it if not then i will post the correct one.